# Windows API, __declspec( thread ) vs CreateThread?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, winapi

I have been trying to learn about threads via the Windows API. I ran across `__declspec( thread )` from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9w1sdazb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), but I don't understand what the difference is between that and `CreateThread()`.

It sounds like you only create the thread on the object? Does that mean that if I wrote a method that does `while(1);` and ran that method in my main class through that object, it would do that in a separate thread? I guess my question is what is `__declspec ( thread )` used for, and should I use that over `CreateThread`?

Sorry if my question is confusing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference between them is huge:

- `__declspec( thread )` is a *storage modifier* that specifies that the declared variable has local storage. That means that each thread owns its own copy of this value. Is the threaded version of globals.

  *C++11* introduces *thread storage modifiers* by the name `thread_local`. Its a *storage modifier*, like `static`.
- `CreateThread()` is a function that will create a new thread and start running some function you specify.

  *C++11* also introduces an entire threading API that you can use to write thread-aware code that will run on (almost) any platform. You can search for `std::thread` and `std::async`...

So basically they are two entirely different things, used for entirely different purposes. If you want to create a new thread using the *Windows API* then use `CreateThread`. If you want a variable to have `thread_local` storage using the *Windows API* then use `__declspec( thread )`. If you can use *C++11*, you should forget about the subtleties of the *Windows API* and use the *Standard API* instead.

Comment: I understand the difference now, thank you! And since you are here, I don't know if this is appropriate to ask, but do you have any materials on Threads that you would recommend me reading? I know google is a click away, but I didn't know if there was a book or website that is really helpful in understanding at least the basics of Threading that you would recommend.